# where we are writing to /proc/net/xt_qtaguid?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, proc

In android_net_TrafficStats.cpp and driver_wired.c **/proc/net/xt_qtaguid** file is reading. I searched fully but i did not find from where this file getting write.

Please help me in finding the file in which we are opening **/proc/net/xt_qtaguid file in write mode.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/datausage/kernel-overview.html) says:

> The per-application/delegated data usage monitoring and tracking functionality relies on the xt_qtaguid module in the android-3.0 Linux kernel (`kernel/net/netfilter/xt_qtaguid`).

This file is never opened for writing; its contents are provided by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to parse /proc/net/xt_qtaguid, you can refer to [NetworkStatsFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/net/NetworkStatsFactory.java)